# Which interface will be the root port in this topology?

Tags: spanning-tree

I am currently studying for my CCNA and the current topic is STP. I ran into this topology and it caused me some confusion.
[image]

I was trying to identify the root port for SW2. Here was my logic for that.

I was told that the cost is added on the receiving interface.

1. The Root Bridge would advertise its BPDUs out of its Gig0/2 interface (let's ignore the Fa0/1 one), with the cost of 0.
2. SW3 would receive it on its Gig0/1 interface and add a cost of 4 to it.
3. It would then forward the frame out its Fa0/2 and Gig0/3 interfaces and after SW2 received them, it would add another +4 cost to it, since both of its interfaces are GigabitEthernet, therefore the cost for both links should be 8.

[image]

Since the cost and the bridge ID of the neighboring device (SW3) are the same for both ports, it would use the lowest port ID/priority as the tiebreaker. So shouldn't Gig0/2 be the root port in its case? Since Fa0/2 has lower port priority, or does it not? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The costs are not the same:

SW2-Gi0/2 links with SW3-**Fa**0/2, so that's only 100 Mbit/s, increasing its root path cost in contrast to SW2-Gi0/3.

You should note that a path cost of 4 for 1 Gbit/s is from the original 802.1D STP and long obsolete. RSTP and MSTP use *20 Tb/s divided by link speed* per default, ie. 20,000 for 1 Gbit/s, 200,000 for 100 Mbit/s, and so on.

Comment: Thank you, I was slightly confused there. If a switch's Gig interface is connected to a Fa interface, they would both autonegotiate the best speed they are capable of transmitting data at, right? Which would be 100 mbps, which has a cost of 19 / 200,000?.

Comment: Yes, exactly - assuming the interfaces are autonegotiating which they should always be.